# How to create Data Frame from list of lists where the inner list has data in a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list mylist where its elements are to be fetched from different files and is available in the format below.

```
mylist = [[{'id':2,'name':"Ted"},{'id':7,'name':"Jack"}],
          [{'id':13,'name':"Jim"},{'id':19,'name':"Tom"}],
          [{'id':73,'name':"Sid"},{'id':89,'name':"Harry"}]]
```

How do I create a dataframe from this list which appears like below?

```
    id    name
0    2    Ted
1    7    Jack
2   13    Jim
3   19    Tom
4   73    Sid
5   89    Harry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first flatten the list of lists into a single list of dictionaries (you can use `itertools.chain` for that) and cast it to the DataFrame constructor:

```
from itertools import chain
out = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(mylist))
```

Output:

```
   id   name
0   2    Ted
1   7   Jack
2  13    Jim
3  19    Tom
4  73    Sid
5  89  Harry
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Used Importing chain from itertools for the scenario

Answer (score 0):

You only have to *flatten* your 2 level list into a simple iterable:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d for lst in mylist for d in lst)
```

It gives as expected:

```
   id   name
0   2    Ted
1   7   Jack
2  13    Jim
3  19    Tom
4  73    Sid
5  89  Harry
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any extra package and a rather straightforward approach is:

```
cols = ['id', 'name']
data = []
for item in mylist:
    data.append(item[0].values())
    data.append(item[1].values())

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
```

It turns your dictionaries to a list `data` of lists.
Output:

```
   id   name
0   2    Ted
1   7   Jack
2  13    Jim
3  19    Tom
4  73    Sid
5  89  Harry
```